# UIImageView won't animate, static image only

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView on my storyboard, which is linked to an outlet in the code. When I run the code, it only shows the static picture that the storyboard shows, not the animation that I create programmatically. Any ideas?

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loading%d",i]];
    [self.images addObject:image];
}
self.loadingView.animationImages = self.images;
self.loadingView.animationDuration = 2;
self.loadingView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.loadingView startAnimating];
```

Note: loadingView is the UIImageView, images is an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Isn't it already allocated in storyboard?

Comment: Did you allocate the 'self.images' array?

Comment: check my answers. both are good options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make run time array you can use like this way.

```
  NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 1 ; i < 4; i++) {

        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"loading%d.jpg", i]]];


    }

    self.loadingView.animationImages = images;
    self.loadingView.animationDuration = 2;
    self.loadingView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [self.loadingView startAnimating];
```

Hope this will help you. It's working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I get confused with allocation when there's so much magic in the storyboard :P

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use array directly like this.

```
NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                 nil];

self.loadingView.animationImages = images;
self.loadingView.animationDuration = 2;
self.loadingView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.loadingView startAnimating];
```